# Pass properties from parent component to all transcluded children component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I would like to pass some properties from a parent to all of his children when those are transcluded (content distribution syntax). In this case, the parent doesen't know (as far as I know) his children, so I don't know how to proceed.

More specificly, I want a way to write this :

```
<my-parent prop1="foo" prop2="bar">
    <my-children></my-children> <!-- Must know content of prop1 and prop2 -->
    <my-children></my-children> <!-- Must know content of prop1 and prop2 -->
</my-parent>
```

Instead of having to write this :

```
<my-parent prop1="foo" prop2="bar">
    <my-children prop1="foo" prop2="bar"></my-children>
    <my-children prop1="foo" prop2="bar"></my-children>
</my-parent>
```

Is it possible ? Thanks.

Comment: Had you consider vuex?

Comment: @AldoRomo88 Please no, I only want to pass a stupid argument to all children, not to manage a full Redux state. Plus that's for reusable components, so the less dependencies it has the better it will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, that's probably not a great deal, but that's the cleanest solution for what I want to do right now. The principle is to create computed properties that will use own component prop if they exist, or get $parent values otherwise. The real prop would then be accessible in this._prop.

```
Vue.component('my-children', {
    props: ["prop1", "prop2"],
    template: "<div>{{_prop1}} - {{_prop2}}</div>",
    computed: {
        _prop1: function() {
            return this.prop1 || this.$parent.prop1;
        },
        _prop2: function() {
            return this.prop2 || this.$parent.prop2;
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a mixin generator that does that in a more elegant way, and with, possibly, multiple levels :

```
function passDown(...passDownProperties) {
    const computed = {};
    passDownProperties.forEach((prop) => {
        computed["_" + prop] = function() {
            return this[prop] || this.$parent[prop] || this.$parent["_" + prop];
        };
    });
    return { computed };
}

Vue.component('my-children', {
    props: ["prop1", "prop2"],
    template: "<div>{{_prop1}} - {{_prop2}}</div>",
    mixins: [passDown("prop1", "prop2")]
});
```

Comment: I like it!,  your solution is cleaner than mine and works very well

Answer (score 1):

Props allow data flow only one level. If you want to perpetuate data, you can use an event bus instead.

Instantiate an event bus with an empty Vue instance in your main file.

```
var bus = new Vue();
```

Then in your parent, emit the event with data to be passed

```
 bus.$emit('myEvent', dataToBePassed);
```

Listen for `myEvent`anywhere you want to pick up the data. In your case, it is done in your child components

```
bus.$on('myEvent', function(data) {
     .....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

At this point (I'm not a vue expert) I just could think in this solution.

Assign every component's props is boring I agree, so why not doing it programmatically?

```
// Create a global mixin
Vue.mixin({
  mounted() { // each component will execute this function after mounted
    if (!this.$children) {
      return;
    }

    for (const child of this.$children) { // iterate each child component
      if (child.$options._propKeys) {
        for (const propKey of child.$options._propKeys) { // iterate each child's props
          // if current component has a property named equal to child prop key
          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this, propKey)) {
            // update child prop value
            this.$set(child, propKey, this[propKey]);

            // create a watch to update value again every time that parent property changes
            this.$watch(propKey, (newValue) => {
              this.$set(child, propKey, newValue);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

This works but you will get an ugly vue warn message:

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value.
```

I'm not sure if this is a good solution but it works, so if you decide to use just keep in mind [Global-Mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin) recomendations:

> Use global mixins sparsely and carefully, because it affects every
> single Vue instance created, including third party components.

Please see a full example at https://github.com/aldoromo88/PropsConvention

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer : I get into something that looked like that but the warning and the need of explicitely watching every prop were a bit repulsive to me. I'll also submit my own solution based on the inverse approach.