# In VueJS is it possible to bind something with v-model that is then rebound to another child?

Tags: vue.js, custom-component

I have an app for which I'm creating a custom component that will output a single row of a table. It contains a numeric field which is user-adjustable, and so *within that custom component* I'm using another custom component from the quasar framework (`q-numeric`). I'm struggling to see how I can bind a variable at the top-level through 2 components - perhaps it can't be done directly, but I was hoping to avoid lots of extra code in the middle component. So far it looks like this from the top down:

In the App.vue template, I have lines like this:

```
<config-item v-model="numParticipants">Number of Participants</config-item>
```

ConfigItem.vue, looks like this:

```
<template>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-right"><slot></slot></td>
    <td class="text-right">
      <q-numeric
        v-model="value"
        :min="min"
        :max="max"
        :step="step"
        @input="$emit('input', value)"
      ></q-numeric>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      label: String,
      value: Number,
      min: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1
      },
      max: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1000
      },
      step: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

But of course that won't work, because I'm now binding the *property* `value` to the `q-numeric`, which will mutate it. Really, I wan't to bind the top-level variable `numParticipants` to the `q-numeric` - is it possible to implement some kind of 'pass through' within my `config-item` component? Or does my component need to have it's own data element which it initialises from the passed-in properties, and updates in response to the `q-numeric`? I know I *can* do that, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution...

Comment: One possible solution might be events (http://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) or you could consider using vuex https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/ to share properties across unrelated components.

Comment: Does my question help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747850/pass-properties-from-parent-component-to-all-transcluded-children-component-in-v

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** You can propagate `v-model`-ability down a hierarchy by making a writable computed based on the prop (the prop must be named 'value'). The `get` function obviously returns the prop value; the `set` function does the `$emit`.

The computed spec is entirely fixed, so I have extracted it as a constant.

```js
const vModelComputed = {
  get() {
    return this.value;
  },
  set(newValue) {
    this.$emit('input', newValue);
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    numParticipants: 1
  },
  components: {
    middleComponent: {
      props: ['value'],
      template: '<div>Value: {{value}} <q-numeric v-model="localValue"></q-numeric></div>',
      computed: {
        localValue: vModelComputed
      },
      components: {
        qNumeric: {
          props: ['value'],
          template: '<div><input v-model="localValue" type="number"> inner value: {{value}}</div>',
          computed: {
            localValue: vModelComputed
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Participants: {{numParticipants}}
  <middle-component v-model="numParticipants"></middle-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply and options! I suspect what I posted as an answer below is very similar to yours, but since I'm using the single file approach, the code looks very different. Also, no need for methods, etc. the way I did it - but maybe I overlooked something? It seems to work in any case...

Comment: @dsl101 The big difference is that I had to implement the equivalent of the `q-numeric`. Also, I was specifically trying to avoid having a data item be copied.

Comment: I'm torn between keeping everything together in the middle component (my answer) and yours which is cleaner but needs vModelComputed. I'd still really like to see Vue support what you've got natively - i.e. remove the need to define vModelComputed. I'm not sure what the syntax would be though - feels something like slots but for props not content. I'll mark this as correct though and leave mine below. Thanks for taking the time :)

Comment: You can certainly inline vModelComputed since you'll only be using it once. I made it a constant because I used it twice, and it is interesting that it is a generally-useful construct for this purpose.

Comment: Actually, that gives me an idea. `vModelComputed` could be turned into a function which generates a new object, and then put as a Vue mixin in the `main.js` file. Then _any_ 'middle' component can just use `localValue: this.vModelComputed()` without needing to inline or define `vModelComputed` at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with - seemed like the simplest approach. I was kind of hoping Vue would have a mechanism to hide this away when the 'middle' component effectively promises not to change the model, but just wants to hand it on to a child.

Basically, I created an intermediary data element `ivalue`, and initialised it in the `mounted()` event, and use the `input()` event of the child to emit an `input()` event back to the parent.

```
<template>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-right"><slot></slot></td>
    <td class="text-right">
      <q-numeric
        v-model="ivalue"
        :min="min"
        :max="max"
        :step="step"
        @input="$emit('input', ivalue)"
      ></q-numeric>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      ivalue: 0
    }),
    mounted () {
      this.ivalue = this.value
    },
    props: {
      label: String,
      value: Number,
      min: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1
      },
      max: {
        type: Number,
        default: 250000
      },
      step: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```