# VueJs watcher vs multiple event listeners on the instance of the model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to figure out which approach is more appropriate / less resource intense. Both examples below will do the same job, but my understanding is that there might be situations where both events `@keyup` and `@change` might be triggered unnecessarily - hence my question, whether `watch` method would be a better option here?

The reason why I also need to check for a `@change` event is when someone simply selects saved input value rather than type it.

```js
<template>
      <input
          type="text"
          :name="name"
          @keyup="update()"
          @change="update()"
          v-model="field"
      >
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            initialValue: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
                default: ''
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                field: this.initialValue
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.update();
        },
        methods: {
            update() {
                this.$emit('input', this.field);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

vs

```js
<template>
      <input
          type="text"
          :name="name"
          v-model="field"
      >
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            initialValue: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
                default: ''
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                field: this.initialValue
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.update();
        },
        watch: {
            field() {
                this.update();
            }
        },
        methods: {
            update() {
                this.$emit('input', this.field);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think what you want is my patented [proxyValue computed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43614124/392102) (just kidding about the patent)

Comment: Thanks @RoyJ - Any particular benefit from using computed property with setter / getter instead of the `watcher` or any of the events above?

Comment: Primarily, it's cleaner. It encapsulates the data item and the watcher in one object, rather than spreading them across data, watch, and methods. I assume the `input` event is handled by the parent updating the prop?

Comment: Yes, that's right - it's just pushing the input outside of the child component to the parent.

Comment: One question however - I can see your getter returns value associated with property `value` - if I was to use the model internally, would it return the actual, updated value or the initial value injected to the component?

Comment: It would return the value of the prop, which changes when the parent changes the value of the variable being passed in. I use `value` because that is what `v-model` works with.

Comment: Great - looks really good.